# Is it possible to embed function (that constructs an element) by value (i.e. anonymous functions/lambdas)

Tags: xslt-3.0

Is it possible to embed a function inside a map (for example) by value e.g.

```
<xsl:function name="kooks:stringAdd" as="xs:string">
    <xsl:param name="s1" as="xs:string"/>
    <xsl:param name="s2" as="xs:string"/>
    <xsl:sequence select="concat($s1,$s2)"/>
</xsl:function>

<xsl:variable name="stringMonoid" as="map(*)">
    <xsl:map>
        <xsl:map-entry key="'zero'" select="''" as="xs:string"/>
        <xsl:map-entry key="'add'" select="kooks:stringAdd#2"/>
    </xsl:map>
</xsl:variable>
```

can i write it (in psuedo xslt) like this.

```
<xsl:variable name="stringMonoid" as="map(*)">
    <xsl:map>
        <xsl:map-entry key="'zero'" select="''" as="xs:string"/>
        <xsl:map-entry key="'add'">
            <xsl:function as="xs:string">
                <xsl:param name="s1" as="xs:string"/>
                <xsl:param name="s2" as="xs:string"/>
                <xsl:sequence select="concat($s1,$s2)"/>
            </xsl:function>
        </xsl:map>
    </xsl:map>
</xsl:variable>
```

---

Clarification, the question is about XSLT functions, I want to be able to construct and return elements (sadly the example returns atomic types), and whilst you can embed xpath expressions that contain inline functions, I'm not sure these can construct elements.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use an anonymous function/lambda expression as a key value e.g.

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
  version="3.0"
  xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
  exclude-result-prefixes="#all"
  expand-text="yes">

  <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>
  
  <xsl:variable name="stringMonoid" as="map(*)"
    select="map {
             'zero' : '',
             'add' : function($s1 as xs:string, $s2 as xs:string) { $s1 || $s2 }
           }"/>

  <xsl:mode on-no-match="shallow-copy"/>

  <xsl:template match="/" name="xsl:initial-template">
    <test>{$stringMonoid?add('This is a ', 'test')}</test>
    <xsl:comment xmlns:saxon="http://saxon.sf.net/">Run with {system-property('xsl:product-name')} {system-property('xsl:product-version')} at {current-dateTime()}</xsl:comment>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

outputs something like (the processor and date info will vary)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<test>This is a test</test>
<!--Run with SAXON HE 10.6 at 2023-10-12T12:13:27.373+02:00-->
```

[Example fiddle using SaxonC HE 12.3](https://saxonc-xmlworkbench.azurewebsites.net/?code=%3C%3Fxml%20version%3D%221.0%22%20encoding%3D%22utf-8%22%3F%3E%0D%0A%3Cxsl%3Astylesheet%20xmlns%3Axsl%3D%22http%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3.org%2F1999%2FXSL%2FTransform%22%0D%0A%20%20version%3D%223.0%22%0D%0A%20%20xmlns%3Axs%3D%22http%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3.org%2F2001%2FXMLSchema%22%0D%0A%20%20exclude-result-prefixes%3D%22%23all%22%0D%0A%20%20expand-text%3D%22yes%22%3E%0D%0A%0D%0A%20%20%3Cxsl%3Aoutput%20method%3D%22xml%22%20indent%3D%22yes%22%2F%3E%0D%0A%20%20%0D%0A%20%20%3Cxsl%3Avariable%20name%3D%22stringMonoid%22%20as%3D%22map%28*%29%22%0D%0A%20%20%20%20select%3D%22map%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%27zero%27%20%3A%20%27%27%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%27add%27%20%3A%20function%28%24s1%20as%20xs%3Astring%2C%20%24s2%20as%20xs%3Astring%29%20%7B%20%24s1%20%7C%7C%20%24s2%20%7D%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%22%2F%3E%0D%0A%0D%0A%20%20%3Cxsl%3Amode%20on-no-match%3D%22shallow-copy%22%2F%3E%0D%0A%0D%0A%20%20%3Cxsl%3Atemplate%20match%3D%22%2F%22%20name%3D%22xsl%3Ainitial-template%22%3E%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%3Ctest%3E%7B%24stringMonoid%3Fadd%28%27This%20is%20a%20%27%2C%20%27test%27%29%7D%3C%2Ftest%3E%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%3Cxsl%3Acomment%20xmlns%3Asaxon%3D%22http%3A%2F%2Fsaxon.sf.net%2F%22%3ERun%20with%20%7Bsystem-property%28%27xsl%3Aproduct-name%27%29%7D%20%7Bsystem-property%28%27xsl%3Aproduct-version%27%29%7D%20at%20%7Bcurrent-dateTime%28%29%7D%3C%2Fxsl%3Acomment%3E%0D%0A%20%20%3C%2Fxsl%3Atemplate%3E%0D%0A%0D%0A%3C%2Fxsl%3Astylesheet%3E%0D%0A&input=&code-type=XSLT&input-type=None).

If you want to create the map with `xsl:map` then

```
  <xsl:variable name="stringMonoid" as="map(*)">
    <xsl:map>
      <xsl:map-entry key="'zero'" select="''"/>
      <xsl:map-entry key="'add'" select="function($s1 as xs:string, $s2 as xs:string) { $s1 || $s2 }"/>
    </xsl:map>
  </xsl:variable>
```

is possible for an anonymous function (created with XPath, admittedly). But it is not clear to me why you would want to use XSLT to create an anonymous function, if your first example has a named function defined with `xsl:function`, why doesn't that suffice?

Comment: yeah, ive just got there myself, so you can in xpath (and embed it in xslt) but can you do it in xslt, I feel awkward writing xpath functions that return things like elements

Comment: I'll mark this as the answer, though as i say, I'd rather it was in xslt not xpath.

Comment: actually can you even write an xpath expression that constructs a new element? so I've removed this as the answer, sorry...it DOES work for the example given, but I can't see how to use it to embed a function that makes a new element (as an xslt function can), I havent moved the goalposts rather just defined better where they are

Comment: @MrDatKookerellaLtd, that depends, of course `function($s as string) { parse-xml-fragment($s) }('<root/>')` is XPath but to construct element or other nodes directly you might need to wait for XPath 4.0 to make some extension like https://www.saxonica.com/html/documentation12/functions/saxon/new-element.html part of the built-in function library.

Comment: ah ok...so for XSLT the answer is no, but for XPath the answer is yes. The 'why' is simply syntax and convenience, what I dont like about XSLT is you can end up with lots and lots of top level named constructs (e.g. functions, templates, variables) etc, when actually they don't need to be globally visible, so embedding them, hides them, and puts everything in 1 place

Comment: the use case is actually constructing excel documents in xml 2003. Here its quite convenient to be able to embed a function that knows how to bind some data to a <Cell>, its neater if I can embed that directly inside the map....I'll look at parse-xml-fragment, but it feels like the cost isnt worth the benefit

Comment: I'll mark it as the answer, because the comments make the situation clear

Comment: XSLT 3 has a `visibility` attribute on `xsl:function` https://www.w3.org/TR/xslt-30/#function-visibility-and-overriding although that is more useful if you work with packages.

Comment: tbh the issue is more "noise" in terms of readability to a human, than coupling concerns. Its nice to put related stuff together in 1 place, in my use case i have a sequence of column defintions, but each bind function, then has to be declared seperately rather than inside the map that defines the column

Comment: If you would like that "feature" of an anonymous inline `xsl:function` in XSLT 4 perhaps take the time to open an issue at https://github.com/qt4cg/qtspecs/issues.

Comment: i have done now, good idea

Comment: I don't understand the '{' and '}' inside the test element, I've seen these in attributes but not in elements (and it doesnt seem to work for me)

Comment: It is a "text value template", new feature in XSLT 3, that allows embedding XPath expressions for text creation, similar as already supported in XSLT 1 and 2 for "attribute value templates"; to enable it, you need the `expand-text="yes"`, that my sample has on the `xsl:styleshet`, though you can put it on any XSLT element you need it or as e.g. <test xsl:expand-text="yes">{current-dateTime}</test>` on literal result elements.